# how can I use Ironpython Working with requests model

Tags: c#, python, python-requests, ironpython

I am trying to run from IronPython a simple get 
I want my C# program to print the result.
I tried so many variations but nothing seems to work.

the code in python:

```
import sys

sys.path.append(r'C:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7\Lib')
import json

import requests

class Myclass:


    def req(self):

        T=str(requests.get('https://api.github.com').status_code)
        if (T=="200"):
            return "<Response [200]>"
        else: return "Error"
```

in c#

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        var engine = Python.CreateEngine();
        dynamic py = engine.ExecuteFile(@"C:\Users\---\Desktop\---\jupy\try4.py");
        dynamic testClass = py.Myclass();


        //string result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(testClass.req());


        MessageBox.Show(testClass.req());
    }
```

(I made a button in word when click I am getting a box with the message)

No matter what I do I keep getting this error: "TypeError: not expecting type ''"

Please Help , it will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: have you checked your python code , is it working fine in stand alone mode .. i.e when executed individually

Comment: Thanks for the help.
Yes the code is working in python environment

Comment: Can you try  MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(testClass.req()));

Comment: still same error :(

Comment: I am not sure about the solution but can you do this , add the following lines and check the type , based on the return type you can do the conversion.   object cc = testClass.req();
    Console.WriteLine(cc.GetType());